# Gallery hover issues

Tags: html, css, hover, gallery

Hi Im trying to add a hover to my gallery images but I think somewhere some code is preventing it from working. Cant work out what it is though. Help would be awesome. Im just pasting html for the first image

```
<div class="images">
<h1>Work</h1>

<div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="images/thumb_diesel.jpg">
            <img src="images/thumb_diesel.jpg" alt="Diesel Car">
            <div class="overlay">
                <h6>Diesel Car</h6>
                <div class="view">View Case Study</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>


.images {
    width:78%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.gallery {
    position: relative;
}

div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.overlay:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}

h6 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.view {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1px;
    border-color: #fff;
    border: 5px;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 90px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Thanks
Steve

Comment: Is it intentional that you have `<div class="images">` with no closing tag?

Comment: there are more images in the gallery, the closing tag is underneath, i just put the code for one image as they all need the same settings. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To make the hover work you need to change the following code in your css:

```
.overlay:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

to:

```
.overlay:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

If you want the text "Diesel Car" to be displayed when someone hovers over the image then you need to add the `title` attribute to the `img` tag.

Thus your `img` tag would be like:

```
<img src="images/thumb_diesel.jpg" alt="Diesel Car" title="Diesel Car">
```

The `alt` attribute doesn't work on some webkit-based browsers.

Comment: Essentially I'm trying to create a hover similar to the type on this site under 'featured', except I'm not fussed about the words animating in and the fade is to black at 0.8 opacity. Ive already added all this I just can't get it to show when the cursor enters the images area.

Comment: @S.Dawson - I have edited the answer. You need to make a simple change in your css to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
.gallery:hover .overlay {
opacity: 1;
```

[Please checkout JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/dulemimate/1/edit?html,css,output)